# Creating nested list in python for a string field

Tags: python

I have the following input data. 
I can create nested list for all other fields exept the last field. The last string field can also contains space in between words(example: Hello! welcome ).

```
input  = ['a1 a2 a3 a4 Hello! welcome','b1 b2 b3 b4 how are you','c1 c2 c3 c4 you are welcome']
```

**Current output**:

```
[['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'Hello!', 'welcome'],   
 ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'how', 'are', 'you'],   
 ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'you', 'are', 'welcome']]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4','Hello! welcome'],     
 ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4','how are you'],   
 ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4','you are welcome']]
```

The below lines of code produces the current output as above but i need to convert the code to get the expected result. Can any one please let me know the way to achieve the expected result.

```
for ix in range(len(input) ):
    nested.append(input[ix:ix + 1])

for i in range(len(nested)):
    list1.append(nested[i][0].split())
```

Comment: Is there any way you can distinguish last field from others except from the example that others are two length words following a pattern (which I presume, is just a demonstration) ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `re.split` for that purpose:

```py
import re

input  = ['a1 a2 a3 a4 Hello! welcome','b1 b2 b3 b4 how are you','c1 c2 c3 c4 you are welcome']

res=[re.split(" ", el, maxsplit=4) for el in input]

print(res)
```

Output:

```py
[['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'Hello! welcome'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'how are you'], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'you are welcome']]

[Program finished]
```

Ref: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: heck i dint even know maxsplit option existed ! 

Comment: I thought he wouldn't split when there's not a digit in the string

Comment: I assumed the format of elements with digits signified, that they are examples, and white space was meant to be the separator. But you right, it isn't really clear from OP's question...

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you meant each sublist only contains 5 elements and the last one can have space between words. If that was the case then you simply need to iterate through `input` list and split each string by only with maximum 5 elements (4 is the highest index)

```
input  = ['a1 a2 a3 a4 Hello! welcome','b1 b2 b3 b4 how are you','c1 c2 c3 c4 you are welcome']

list1 = []

for i in input:
    list1.append(i.split(' ', 4))

print(list1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

My initial instinct would be :-

```
example = 'a1 a2 a3 a4 Hello! welcome'

list1 = example.split(" ")
list1[4] = ' '.join(list1[4:])
del list1[5:]
```

Expected output stored in 
`list1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'Hello! Welcome']`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!